# Can't get Jest to run named import

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

This is a Typescript Jest test with a Typescript create-react-app project.

I have the following

```
/* global test, expect */
import React from 'react';
import { getCurrentUser } from '../../utils/authUtils';


test('Bidding component runs without errors', () => {
  jest.mock('../../utils/authUtils', () => {
    return {
      __esModule: true,
      getCurrentUser: jest.fn(() => ({ uid: 'user124' })),
    };
  });
  console.log(getCurrentUser());
});
```

When `getCurrentUser()` is called in the test it is calling the original imported function, not the declared mock. What am I doing wrong?

This function is actually used in my component that will be under test once I have this working, but I'm assuming if it doesn't work here, it won't work there either?

Comment: See the createMockFromModule method -  https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestcreatemockfrommodulemodulename